# How to avoid overwriting a value through for loop in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Below is the one I coded. The problem here is I have values 1, 2, and 3 in the A matrix and hence at the output A has all the values 1.
The result I expect is:

```py
A = np.matrix([[1, 2, 2, 1], 
               [1, 1, 3, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 3]]).
```

Any help is appreciated. Sorry for my poor writing. Thank you!

```
A = np.matrix([[1, 15, 23, 2], [3, 2, 56, 7], [2, 6, 8, 25]])
bound = np.array([1, 15, 25, 56])
for i in range(3, 0, -1):
    A[np.logical_and(bound[i - 1] <= A, A <= bound[i])] = i
```

Comment: `numpy.searchsorted` ? [`np.searchsorted(bound, A, side='left')`](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/1274caf4.py)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. The first element of the output  matrix is 0. I expect there 1

Comment: if `1` maps to `1`, why `15` also maps to `1` ? shouldn't it be `2` ? Since there's a `15` in `bound` ?

Comment: But anyways, you can try `np.searchsorted(bound, A, side='right')` to see if it gives what you need.

Comment: Oh sorry for that!. Yes 15 must be 2. I tried with np.searchsorted(bound, A, side='right'). It doesn't work

Comment: Also, `25` should convert to `3`, right? Please checkout the solution below and elaborate if this is not what you were looking for. Thank you

Comment: @Ehsan Yes it should be 3. Sorry for that! Your below solution worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Joyce You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer to close the question. And a good way to thank in SO is upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is saving the changed elements in a separate `mask_`:

```
mask_ = np.ones_like(A, dtype=bool)
for i in range(3,0,-1):
    mask = np.logical_and(bound[i - 1] <= A, A <= bound[i])
    A[np.multiply(mask_,mask)] = i
    mask_ = np.multiply(mask_,~mask)
```

output:

```
[[1 2 2 1]
 [1 1 3 1]
 [1 1 1 3]]
```